# How do I make index into a "normal" column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've just created a new dataframe, that is a subset of a larger one. (image link below)
However, it is making the first column and index, which I do not want.
I've tried looking for answers, but everything seems to relate to resetting and index

I either want to add a column that will serve as a new index (just numbered would be fine), or just change this column so its no longer an index

[image: Data Frame Subset]

Comment: Please upload your image into the Stack Overflow text editor, into the question directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How exactly did you create the DataFrame? Did you try reading that documentation, to look for a way to add the index directly during creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# keep the index as a column
df = df.reset_index()

# drop it
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```